# How to limit while loop by time in powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, time, while-loop, limit

I have a script which starts a process only after specific service is running.
It's a loop that's trying to `Get-Service` its status.
I can't find how to limit loop by time.

The part where I'm stuck:

```
#add Start button
$button_start = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button_start.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,70)
$button_start.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
$button_start.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$button_start.font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$button_start.BackColor = "seashell"
$button_start.Text = "Start"
$button_start.Add_Click({
    #add statement
    while ((Get-Service -ComputerName $textBox_IP.text -ServiceName wscsvc).Status -ne "Running") {
        # Pause before next check
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }

    #only then..
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\username\Desktop\software.exe" -verb RunAs -ArgumentList $textBox_IP.text
})

$Form_remoteControl.Controls.Add($button_start)
```

I've tried internet searching information on network without any success.

Answer (score 3):

Define a time limit and check if the current time exceeds that limit.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)
while (... -or (Get-Date) -le $limit) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

If you want to skip starting the external program when the service still isn't running after that add another check after the loop upon which you return:

```
if ((Get-Service ...).Status -ne "Running") {
    return
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay but i didn't get how to insert it in my script

Comment: @ATX-750K You have only one `while` loop in the code snippet you posted, so adjust that according to what I outlined in my answer. If you're really unable to do that integration yourself you may want to find a PowerShell tutorial first. I'm not going to provide you with a turnkey solution here.

Comment: ok, so you don't know, that's fine. thanks anyway, appreciated .

Comment: while (... -or (Get-Date) -gt $limit) { 
should be: while (... -or (Get-Date) -le $limit) { 
, but thanks for main idea

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to stop a service and wait until it is stopped or timeout applies.
You can modify to start a service.

```
Function StopService ($serv)
{
    Write-Host "Config service " $serv  " ..."         
    $service = Get-Service $serv -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($service)
    {
        if($service.status -eq "running")
        {
            write-host "Stop service" $serv
            Stop-Service $serv  -Force

            # Wait until service is stopped (max. 1 minute)
            $acttime  = 0
            $waittime = 100
            $maxtime  = 60000

            $TestService = Get-Service $serv
            While($TestService | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'})
            {                     
                Start-Sleep -m $waittime
                $acttime += $waittime
                if ($acttime -gt $maxtime)
                {
                    write-host "ERROR: Service" $serv " could not be stopped!" -ForegroundColor Red                       
                    return $False
                } 
            }   
        } 
        else
        {
            write-host "Service already stopped!" -ForegroundColor Green   
            return $True             
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        write-host "Service not installed" -ForegroundColor Green
        return $True
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you **not** using any polling `While` loops (with `Start-Sleep` cmdlets) in a Windows forms interface. It will stall your interface for important form events as button clicks etc.
Instead, I would anticipate on the [Windows.Forms Timer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8) by creating a timer event and take appropriate checks and actions after a certain time period (e.g. a new `Start-Process` depending on a service state).